# I am getting this error? Could someone help me resolve this?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

error Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Ruby Version Manager (https://rvm.io/rvm/install)
2. Install Ruby 2.7.5 (`rvm install 2.7.5`)
3. Use Ruby 2.7.5 (`rvm use 2.7.5`)